# Facing issue in cypress when Input with autocus and blur in StencilJS

Tags: cypress, shadow-dom, stenciljs

I am facing issue with cypress in my project. I am having an input which is appear on click of search icon and disappear on blue event of the input.

I am writing cypress test to check my functionality, here I am facing a problem whenever I type in input with cypress .type() method but it is firing **blur** event of the input every time.

Once **blur** event is fired my input ill disappear from the DOM.
It will works fine if I remove `autofocus` from input.

Please can someone help me to write proper cypress test for my use case. Thank you.

**component.ts**

```js
export class SearchTable {
  private searchInput: HTMLInputElement;
  @State() isSearchOpen: boolean = false;
  
  
  private handleClickSearch = () => {
    this.isSearch = !this.isSearch;
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.searchInput.focus();
    })
  }
  
  handleBlur = () => {
    console.log('blur event called!!!')
    this.isSearch = !this.isSearch;
  }
  
  render() {
  
    return (
      <div slot="right-panel" data-test-id={`${this.dataTestId}-right-panel-slot`}>
            {this.isSearch ?
              <input data-test-id="input-search" onBlur={this.handleBlur} ref={el => (this.searchInput = el as HTMLInputElement)}/> :
              <icon-component onClick={this.handleClickSearch} dataTestId={`${this.dataTestId}-search-icon`} icon="search" />
            }
          </div>
    )
  }
```

cypress test

```js
it.only("check search functionality with empty data", () => {

    cy.getSearchSection()

      .find("icon-component").click()

      .getSearchSection()

      .findAllByTestId(`input-search`)

      .type('volume4444')

      .wait(600)

      .should('have.value', 'volume4444');

  });
```

Comment: How about you first `.click()`after you find the input box and then write type with a delay `.type('volume4444', {delay: 30})`

Comment: @AlapanDas, type() will call click internally right, so that time it is calling blur event so that moment input ill disappear.

Comment: 1. Where does the test fail? 2. Why do you think `.type('volume4444')` causes blur?

Comment: @Seke, in ```.type()``` my test case is failing so, and blur event console is printing

Comment: @Seke, it will work fine, if I remove autofocus by default.